# SQL Server Pivot -> Sum rows by condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a question regarding the pivot function in SQL Server. I have a table which looks like the following:

```
L  |  SH | SUM | KTYPE
----------------------
L1 |  A  | 10  | 1    
L1 |  B  | 12  | 1
L1 |  A  | 14  | 2    
L1 |  B  | 19  | 2        
L2 |  A  |  9  | 1 
L2 |  B  | 25  | 1    
L3 |  A  |  2  | 1   
L3 |  B  |  2  | 1  
L4 |  A  |  9  | 1   
L4 |  B  | 23  | 1   
...
```

As a result, I would like to have the following structure:

```
   |     1     |    2      |   Total   |
L  |  A  |  B  | A  |   B  | A  |   B  |
----------------------------------------
L1 |  10 | 12  | 14 |  19  | 24 |  31  |
L2 |  9  | 25  | 0  |   0  |  9 |  25  |
L3 |  2  |  2  | 0  |   0  |  2 |   2  |
L4 |  9  | 23  | 0  |   0  |  9 |  23  |
...
```

If I am serious, I have no idea how to do that. I was able to "pivot" the data by `KTYPE`, but not by `KTYPE` and `SH`. Can somebody tell me if this is possible and give me a hint?

Thanks in advance!
tommy

Comment: I think your best best would be to concatenate KTYPE+SH into a single value... and pivot that.

Comment: This is something you will have to do with a reporting tool, SSRS etc. In ssrs this can be easily achieved using Matrix and grouping by Columns. Sql Server is best for storing and retrieving data, Displaying data should be handled at application layer.

Comment: @M.Ali - I am wondering how SSRS would do it. Then, I'll try to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample per my comment above about concatenating the fields.

```
DECLARE @TMP TABLE (L VARCHAR(2), SH VARCHAR(1), SUM INT, KTYPE INT)

INSERT INTO @TMP
SELECT 'L1','A',10,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'L1','B',12,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'L1','A',14,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'L1','B',19,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'L2','A',9,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'L2','B',25,1 UNION ALL   
SELECT 'L3','A',2,1 UNION ALL  
SELECT 'L3','B',2,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'L4','A',9,1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'L4','B',23,1

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT CAST(KTYPE AS VARCHAR)+SH AS KTYPESH,SUM VAL,L FROM @TMP) DATATABLE
PIVOT (SUM([VAL])
       FOR KTYPESH IN ([1A],[1B],[2A],[2B])) PIVOTTABLE
```

Comment: Your query seems to be correct. Output - L 1A 1B 2A 2B
L1 10 12 14 19
L2 9 25 NULL NULL
L3 2 2 NULL NULL
L4 9 23 NULL NULL

Comment: Above format - column names, 1st row, 2nd row...etc.